# Remove Office 365 Hybrid Configuration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, office, hybrid-solution

I set up our on premise SharePoint environment in a hybrid Office 365 environment a few weeks ago, but now I want to remove the configuration. I deleted the 2 service applications mentioned in this guide - 
http://www.sprocks.io/2016/07/sharepoint-2016-remove-hybrid.html but all my Mysite links etc are still sending me to the Office 365 login screen when clicked. Has anyone else had this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: what you configured in Hybrid, MySites in cloud and UPA on prem?

Comment: have you tried to remove the server to server authentication?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP Ive set up hybrid sites. yes UPA on prem.

Answer (score 0):

Did the issue occur in SharePoint 2016?

If so, you could go to central administration->office365-> Configure hybrid OneDrive and Sites features->remove the mysite URL and select None for hybrid feature.

Comment: Hi, I get the "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list." error while trying to navigate to the cloudconfiguration.aspx page.